# Register validating with web service

Tags: forms, hooks, users, services

I've altered the default register form into multistep and its connecting with web service SOAP.
The first step is validating well and gets the webservice response.
The second step of the form is using the default fields user, pass, pass_confirm and email.

I have two issues: When I'm passing the XML string to the web service and when response with error message, lets say in this case ("this user its already registered), Drupal its registering the user. How could prevent Drupal to register if there is a error from the web service? Here is a part of the code. Its a submit handler that connects with the web service.

```
<?php
**
 * Submit handler for user registration form.
 *
 */
function custom_register_register_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {

    $egn = $form_state['values']['egn'];
    $card_mask = $form_state['values']['last_digits'];
    $auth_code = $form_state['values']['authorization_code'];
    $trn_date = $form_state['values']['transcation_date'];
    $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $session_id = session_id();
    $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    $pass = $form_state['values']['pass'];
    $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];



$xml_string = '<reqRegRequestCardHolder>
  <egn>' . $egn . '</egn>
  <cardMaskLastDigits>' . $card_mask . '</cardMaskLastDigits>
  <authCode>' . $auth_code . '</authCode>
  <trnDate>' . $trn_date . '</trnDate>
  <username>' . $name . '</username>
  <password>' . $pass . '</password>
  <email>' . $email . '</email>
  <ip_address>' . $ip_address . '</ip_address>
  <session_id>' . $session_id . '</session_id>
  <language>bg</language>
</reqRegRequestCardHolder>';



    $client = new nusoap_client('http://10.10.60.80:8090/CardHolderAuthentication.asmx?wsdl', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'trace' => 1, 'exeptions' => true));
    $client -> soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $client -> decode_utf8 = FALSE;



    $result = $client->call('CreateRegistrationRequest',array('_xml'=>$xml_string));

    $response = simplexml_load_string($result['CreateRegistrationRequestResult']);

    $status = $response->status;





    if($status == 'SUCCESS') {

        $requestId = $response->requestID; 
        //drupal_set_message("request id : ".$requestId, 'status');
        //$form_state['step'] = 2;

            }
    elseif ($status == 'ERROR') {

        $description = $response->error->descr_bg;


        $form_state['step'] = 1;
        drupal_set_message($description, 'error');
    }
    else {

    }

    dpm($form_state);   

}
```

The other issue is: I'm using the PHP function simplexml_load_string() to receive a response from web service as a array.
On my multistep form on the first step simplexml_load_string is working properly, but on the next step when the user is filling the default fields user, pass, pass_confirm and email after submitting the form there's an error: `Exception: Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed in session_write_close()`.

Comment: you should place the above code in the (form_validate())validate_function() and set a form_set_error() if response shows failed status.